# No getApiClient() in google play game services BaseGameUtils

Tags: java, android, google-play-services, google-play-games

I've just added google play services leaderboard to my game, but there are some problems. I can't start leaderboard activity. Here is my code

```
startActivityForResult(Games.Leaderboards.getLeaderboardIntent(getApiClient(), "leaderboard_id"), 5000);
```

problem is that there isn't any getApiClient() method. Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

You have to use an object of type GoogleApiClient. Your code should be like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener{
        GoogleApiClient mGoogleClient;
        ...

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            ...
            //Google Game 
            mGoogleClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this, this, this)
           .addApi(Games.API)
           .addScope(Games.SCOPE_GAMES)
           .setGravityForPopups(Gravity.TOP | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL)
           .build();

        }

        @Override
        public void onStart(){
            super.onStart();
            //Here is a good place to connect with Google Api
            mGoogleClient.connect();
        }

        @Override
        public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {}

        @Override
        public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {}

        @Override
        public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The [Games APIs doc](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/init) points to this method in the BaseGameUtils library in the Android Samples project as well as similar methods such as getApiClientBuilder():

"If your game wants to add additional Google Play services APIs or scopes to the GoogleApiClient managed by BaseGameActivity, it can do this by calling getApiClientBuilder() on the GameHelper object" in BaseGameUtils.

I don't yet see those methods in [BaseGameUtils on github](https://github.com/playgameservices/android-samples) and am guessing that they will be updated at some point.

**UPDATE**: Looks like a GameHelper update in BaseGameUtils is [on its way](https://github.com/playgameservices/android-samples/issues/46).

Answer (score 1):

if your main activity extends BaseGameActivity like-
public class MainActivity extends BaseGameActivity

then you can use getApiClient() anywhere in that activity.

however if you want to access getApiClient() from another activity(or non-activity class) then do this-

public class MainActivity extends BaseGameActivity{

```
static GoogleApiClient myclient;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    myclient=getApiClient();
}
```

...}

then you just have to call "MainActivity.myclient"
instead of "getApiClient()" from other classes.